# How is a sequentially accessible device made randomly accessible?

Tags: linux, filesystems, drivers, devices, io

1. If a device offers only sequential access not random access, can a
   device driver or a file system make the device look like randomly accessible to users?

   If yes, is this done by providing buffer/cache to the device?
2. For example, here is what I heard but not sure if correct:

   - rewind-only tape offers only sequential access
   - for such a tape device,  any movement backward from the current position might require rewinding the tape to the beginning and then
     moving forward

   What makes such a tape randomly accessible: changing the device itself at device/hardware level, a device driver of
   the tape,  or  something else?

   Given such a tape made randomly accessible , if I `open()`  it with `O_DIRECT`, will
   the tape become sequentially accessible only and not randomly
   accessible?

Comment: I’ll say this again: `O_DIRECT` is irrelevant as far as random access is concerned.

Comment: Thanks. I remember you said with `O_DIRECT`, random accessiblity is up to the device itself. So I am asking if a device is only sequentially accessible, can driver or filesystem make it look like randomlly accessibly  to users?

Comment: I understand what you’re asking, I don’t understand what `O_DIRECT` has to do with it and why you mention it in your question. It gives the impression you think that `O_DIRECT` causes the tape to become sequentially accessible only.

Comment: @StephenKitt I heard that  tape is accessible only sequentially. I guess some device driver can make a tape appear randomly accessible to a user. If I `open()` the device file of the tape with `O_DIRECT`, it will bypass all or most services from the filesystem and OS (including driver), and then does it mean that the tape becomes sequentially accessible again?

Comment: `O_DIRECT` bypasses caches, it doesn’t bypass the driver. See my first comment.

Comment: @StephenKitt  Does O_DIRECT bypass the filesystem and device-independent OS services, but not the device-dependent OS services (such as device driver)? Is sequential /random accessibility  provided by device driver?

Comment: Again, `O_DIRECT` bypasses caches. It doesn’t bypass the file system or anything other than caches. Supported access patterns do depend on the driver, yes (but providing random access on top of a purely sequential device is going to be limited).

Comment: @StephenKitt O_DIRECT doesn't just bypass caches. The quote from Operating System Concepts seems to say it bypass all filesystem and OS services, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/473841/674 so I am  not clear.

Comment: I’m not sure what else to say; sourcejedi’s answer is correct. On Linux, `O_DIRECT` bypasses caches, that’s all.

Answer (score 1):

If the device can move back and forth without external intervention, then yes, you could make a device driver make it *appear* to be random access.  You could do that in a few ways:

1. If the device is small with respect to the amount of main memory available, you could mirror the content of the device in memory where random access possible.
2. If the device is too big to store in main memory, you could page it -- basically do (1) but on segments of the underlying content.  Any read/write to a page not currently in memory would be extremely slow because the "old" page would need to get flushed and the new page would need to be read into memory.

Any writes would eventually need to be flushed back to the underlying media.  That'd likely be an extremely slow process, and would raise questions like "does the media support partials updates" (i.e., can the OS overwrite only the data that was updated, or does it need to re-write the entire media)?

All that said, it being "doable" doesn't make it a good idea.  You're confined to the behavior of the hardware.  If it doesn't provide true random access, faking it will be very slow.